# How to create a running total using blade

Tags: php, web-services, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am trying to replicate the look of a bank statment in blade so far I can display the credits and debits correctly with following code but I am failing to grasp how to create a running total

```
<tbody>
@foreach($customers['$resources'] as $resource)
<tr>
<td  class="date"> {{-- */$date = $resource['date'];
preg_match( "#/Date\((\d{10})\d{3}(.*?)\)/#", $date, $match );/*--}}{{date( 'd/m/Y', $match[1] )}} </td>
<td>{{$resource['reference']}}</td>
@if ($resource['amountNet'] >=0.1)
<td  class="currency">
<span>£{{number_format((float)$resource['amountPaid'], 2, '.', '')}} </span>
</td>
<td  class="currency">
<span> </span>
</td>
<td  class="currency">
<span> £{{-- */
$runningTotal = $resource['amountNet'];
if ($resource['amountNet'] < 0) {
  $runningTotal = $runningTotal - $resource['amountNet'];
} else {
  $runningTotal = $runningTotal + $resource['amountNet'];
}   /*--}}{{$runningTotal}}
</span>
</td>
@elseif($resource['amountNet'] <=  1 )
<td  class="currency">
<span> </span>
</td>
<td  class="currency">
<span>£{{number_format((float)$resource['amountPaid'], 2, '.', '')}} </span>
</td>
<td  class="currency">
<span> £ </span>
</td>
@endif
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

the "$resource['amountNet']" is a signed value where as the "$resource['amountPaid']" is just a value I do not have access to the data base to amend it. What have so far is the first line is the opening balance so the first line balance should equal that balance but it is double and the next balance should be +/- depending on whether its a credit or debit any help would be appreciated

Comment: It's a little unclear what exactly you're asking. Are you trying to sum all of the 'amountNet' in each resource for one running total?

Comment: yes  I believe that is what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: Then you need to set your $runningTotal variable outside of the for-loop scope. When you set it within your for-loop, at every iteration the variable is overridden.

Set $runningTotal = 0; outside of your loop, then do += (not =) within your for-loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're overriding your $runningTotal variable at each iteration of your for-loop.

You need to set that variable **outside** of your for-loop scope, then update it within your for-loop:

```
<tbody>
{{$runningTotal = 0}}
@foreach($customers['$resources'] as $resource)
...
£{{ $runningTotal += $resource['amountNet'] }}
...
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: this worked perfectly when i made the following changes "<span> £{{--*/$runningTotal += $resource['amountNet'];/*--}} {{$runningTotal}} </span>" thank  you Devon for oyur help

Comment: I'm happy to help. Also, this new syntax should work better, the initial version had an extra ';' that caused issues. This way you don't need to reference the variable again, just to print it. :)

Comment: Thank's Devon, I am using 4.2 and in blade you need to add --*/ /*-- and put the code between the back slashes or it just echo's out everything between the curly braces

Comment: Interesting, thanks for letting me know. I was running 5.2. Good luck!